# SwiftUI 2 View Models in a View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this view which takes as a param its own View Model. Inside this view I need to show another view which in order for it to be displayed, needs its own View Model. So I present the `Purchase` view and then inside the `Purchase` view I need to display the details of the actual item which was purchased. So I pass as a parameter also the `ItemViewModel`. Both `PurchaseViewModel` and `ItemViewModel` are used on other views also.

It could happen in the feature that I would also need `ClientViewModel` which would be used to display data about the actual buyer of this item. Does this mean that I would need to pass also `@ObservedObject var clientViewModel: ClientViewModel` as a parameter?

My question is: Is this approach good or there is a better way to do this ?

```
struct PurchaseView: View {
    @ObservedObject var purchaseViewModel: PurchaseViewModel
    @ObservedObject var itemViewModel: ItemViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(purchaseViewModel.title)
            ItemView(itemViewModel: itemViewModel)
        }
    }
}

class Purchase {
    let senderID: String
    let receiverID: String
    var status: PurchaseStatus
    var item: Item?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by considering the relationship of the *models*, not the *view models*.

For example, you could make a case that a `Purchase` involves one or more items (`Item`) and a purchaser (`Client`).  In this case you would actually create a model something like:

```
class Purchase {
    var items = [Item]()
    var client: Client
    ...
}
```

And your `PurchaseViewModel` would reflect this, containing the `ItemViewModel` and `ClientViewModel`

```
    let clientViewModel: ClientViewModel
    let itemsViewModels: [ItemViewModel]

    init(purchase: Purchase) {
        self.clientViewModel = ClientViewModel(client:purchase.client)
        self.itemsViewModels = purchase.items.map { ItemViewModel(item:$0) }
    }
```

If you have a hierarchy of views that need some unrelated models then you can consider using the environment, especially for models that are "global"

For example, say that the user was looking at an item detail, but they were not yet making a purchase (So there is no `Purchase` yet) and you want to have a button that shows them their `Client` detail.

You could pass the `ItemViewModel` explicitly to the `ItemDetailView`:

```
struct ItemListView {
   ...

   Button(action: { ItemDetailView(item:someItemView) }) 
       { ... }

}


struct ItemDetailView {
    ...
    Button(action: { ClientView() }) {
        Text("Client detail")
    }
}

struct ClientDetailView {

   @EnvironmentObject client: ClientViewModel
   ...
}
```

You can inject the `ClientViewModel` into the environment at a suitable point, such as the root view or even scene delegate.

If you have a hierarchy of views that need these models, but not all views need all models, you could use the environment to provide the various models rather than directly injecting them via initialiser parameters.

Comment: do you mean to create an environment object which contains both `PurchaseViewModel` and `ClientViewModel` and then pass this EO to the view? Can you provide a small ex in code please?

Comment: No, I mean add all three models to the environment independently. Then a particular view can just declare `@EnvironmentObject` properties for the models it needs. I will add some code shortly.

Comment: I think I get the idea but I will wait for the code just to be sure. also at some point I need to pass a `model` for each of the `PurchaseViewModel` (purchase: purchase)  and ClientViewModel (client: client).

Comment: so I think I got it. one question regarding the 2nd scenario, at which point do I pass the client model to the clientEnviromentObject. I can not do it on Scenedelegate for ex because at this point I do not know the actual client. Should I create the instance in Scenedelegate and then have a methd setClient(client: client) later for ex?

Comment: You can inject an object into the environment at any level by adding `.environmentObject(client)` to the view.  That environment is then inherited by everything below.  For something global like a client, I would have a `GlobalModel` or similar that is injected into the environment by the scene delegate.  That model would have a `Client?` property.  Or it could have a `Client` property that was initialised with a reference to an `AnonymousClient` and you update the property when you identify the actual client. Setting the client would be a function of the model, not the scene delegate

Answer (score 2):

You could make the `PurchaseViewModel` contain the `ItemViewModel` and `ClientViewModel` as properties in the same way that the `PurchaseView` contains the `ItemView` and `ClientView`.

That would make `PurchaseViewModel` responsible for creating the instances of the other view models. The parent of `PurchaseView` would no longer need to know about the implementation of `PurchaseView`.

Comment: You mean to put a viewModel inside another viewModel? like this? `class RequestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var itemViewModel: ItemViewModel
    @Published var clientViewModel: ClientViewModel
}`